# Auto populating text boxes on an Access 2003 form when value selected in combo box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, combobox

I am building a form in access database.

I have a combo box which is linked to a query which is looking up a unique reference number from a table called Tbl_Submitted_Requests.

What I need the form to do is auto populate the other text boxes when the user selects the unique reference from the combo box. How can I get the text boxes to auto populate with the data that is associated with each unique reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, bind your form to Tbl_Submitted_Requests or better, a query that uses this table, you can do this with the form wizard or by setting the Record Source property of the form. Each of the textboxes will also need to have a control source set to the name of a field (column) Next, add a combo and choose "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combobox" from the wizard options.

Comment: I have done the above and have selected the unique reference for the combo box using the wizard. However, when I select any of the unique references in the combobox the text boxes are not auto populating? Help please! ;)

Comment: Try starting from the beginning to spot the problem. Create a form based on the table using the form wizard and then add the combo using the combo wizard.

Comment: Starting from the beginning has solved it - thanks for your help!

Comment: @Steve Clark: if the problem is solved then you should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with Remou's response, with one small edification. Crate a new form, and drag all of the fields from the relevant query or table onto this form. Alternatively, you can drag them from the field chooser if the form has already been bound. Then, create your combo-box, and choose "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combobox" from the wizard options.

Comment: You have something against the form wizard?